# Can't activate Lua-support in freeswitch

Tags: lua, ubuntu-18.04, freeswitch

If activating Lua-Support in modules.conf, **./configure, make , install** yields the following error:

*

```
making install mod_lua
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/jklou/jkl/fs/freeswitch-1.8.2/src/mod/languages/mod_lua'
  CXX      mod_lua_la-mod_lua.lo
mod_lua.cpp:37:17: fatal error: lua.h: 没有那个文件或目录
compilation terminated.
Makefile:687: recipe for target 'mod_lua_la-mod_lua.lo' failed
make[4]: *** [mod_lua_la-mod_lua.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/jklou/jkl/fs/freeswitch-1.8.2/src/mod/languages/mod_lua'
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'mod_lua-install' failed
make[3]: *** [mod_lua-install] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/jklou/jkl/fs/freeswitch-1.8.2/src/mod'
Makefile:587: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jklou/jkl/fs/freeswitch-1.8.2/src'
Makefile:3257: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jklou/jkl/fs/freeswitch-1.8.2'
Makefile:3729: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

*

so Lua cannot be used.

Google: Several Forums advise to refresh the GIT-repository, but this cannot be used because I need an older Version of freeswitch

Comment: "没有那个文件或目录" means "No such file or directory". This implies your include paths aren't set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

```
apt-get install libreadline-dev apt-get install lua5.2 lua5.2-doc liblua5.2-dev
```

then copy LUA-sh-files to LUA-mod-directory of Freeswitch:

```
cp /usr/include/lua5.2/*.h [Installationsverzeichnis Freeswitch]]/src/mod/languages/mod_lua/
```

then link it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua.so
```

then repeat make install (don't repeat ./configure and make)

```
sudo make install
```

this worked perfectly for me (Freeswitch 1.8.2. and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS running in Virtual Box)